# How to make loop for this?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

Is it possible to do this? Here is my code:

```
$sponsor1 = "Sponsor 1";
$sponsor2 = "Sponsor 2";
$sponsor3 = "Sponsor 3";
$sponsor4 = "Sponsor 4";
$sponsor5 = "Sponsor 5";
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) {
if($sponsor.$i){
echo $sponsor.$i;
echo "<br>";
}}
```

I want the above loop can display like this. I want something like this:

```
Sponsor 1
Sponsor 2
Sponsor 3
Sponsor 4
Sponsor 5
```

Comment: This is what __arrays__ are used for.

Comment: Read about arrays here -> https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Agreed with @u_mulder  or you can do like this:- https://eval.in/974401

Comment: Thank You Very Much for repply my questions :) problem solved. thank you.. thank you..

Answer (score 4):

You can construct your variables using `PHP` variable variable, read here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

```
$sponsor1 = "Sponsor 1";
$sponsor2 = "Sponsor 2";
$sponsor3 = "Sponsor 3";
$sponsor4 = "Sponsor 4";
$sponsor5 = "Sponsor 5";
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) {
   $v = 'sponsor'.$i;
   echo $$v;
   echo "<br>";
}
```

Notice the `$$v`

Comment: Thank You Very Much for repply my questions :) problem solved. thank you.. thank you..

Comment: Remember the bit in Jurassic Park where Dr. Malcolm says *"Yeah, but your scientists were so preoccupied with whether or not they could, they didn't stop to think if they should."*? ... similar thing applies here.

Comment: Yeah, of course.
But what I'm learned to do is to give simplest answer to the question.
The consideration whether it is good for particular use case is out of scope of this question.

Answer (score 4):

There are three possible solutions:

1.Create array and iterate over it. (***Best***)

```
$sponsor_array = ["Sponsor 1","Sponsor 2","Sponsor 3","Sponsor 4","Sponsor 5"];
foreach($sponsor_array as $sponsor){
 echo $sponsor;
 echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/974403

2.Direct use `for()` loop (***Better***)

```
<?php

for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) {

  echo "Sponsor ".$i;
  echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/974401

3.use [Variables variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) concept (***Not recomended for your case***)

```
$sponsor1 = "Sponsor 1";
$sponsor2 = "Sponsor 2";
$sponsor3 = "Sponsor 3";
$sponsor4 = "Sponsor 4";
$sponsor5 = "Sponsor 5";
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) {
   $v = 'sponsor'.$i;
   echo $$v;
   echo "<br>";
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/974405

Comment: Thank You Very Much for repply my questions :)

Answer (score 2):

The proper solution is to use an array.

```
$sponsors = [
    "Sponsor 1",
    "Sponsor 2",
    "etc"
];

foreach ($sponsors as $thisSponsor) {
    echo "$thisSponsor<br />\n";
}
```

If for whatever reason you can't use an array directly you could always do the following:

```
foreach ([$sponsor1, $sponsor2, $sponsor3, $sponsor4, $sponsor5] as $thisSponsor) {
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much for repply my questions :)